# Iframe automatically goes full screen using Ionic 3.9.2 on iOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, iframe

Iframe automatically goes full screen using Ionic 3.9.2 on iOS.

I've tried removing all the fullscreen tags. I notice that it is not happening anywhere else. Only happens on iOS. On other devices, I have to manually make it full screen.

**Why does Iframe automatically go full screen on iOS?**

```
<iframe src="https://d1mlukbqb3dh9w.cloudfront.net/PortraitCourse/Module01/Module01Section1/story.html" height="655" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Comment: So you want to know why it's automatically loaded? Or why it's full screen when it's loaded? Except ios, how does other work when you load them?

Comment: I want to know why it goes full screen automatically? On other devices, you have to manually full screen it.

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: @JinLee I want to know why it automatically goes full screen. On the rest of the devices, if it loads it does not automatically go full screen an dyou have to do it manually.

Comment: You are not getting enough attention for your question. Let me start a bounty for you.

Comment: Well, I guess this is a rare issue. I tried. :)  Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

A while ago I would have been able to provide you with a spot-on answer. Unfortunately I no longer have access to the resources I would need to do so... meaning my answer won't be a complete solution.

IFRAME, on iOS, works slightly differently than on Android. Getting an IFRAME to take only the height you want is not simply a matter of setting the HEIGHT property on the tag as the rendering engine works differently. You'll have to play around with CSS both in the container of the tag and in the contents of the body itself.

Try proceeding as follows:

1. prepare a mock target page that doesn't take all the height, make
   its background red and see how much space it takes
2. make the mock page longer than the height of the screen by adding lots of text and images to it and observe the change
3. wrap the IFRAME in a DIV and set the `style=height: xxx` of the div, as well as its `overflow`.
4. wrap the contents of the mock page in a div, setting its `height`, `overflow`, `position` and `display` style
   properties to control its appearance.
5. repeat step (4) with both the HTML and BODY tags of the mock page.

Playing with these in real-time using Safari to alter their values will prove most useful. It was to me at least, when I had the problem over an year ago.